# AC LED Dimming using Arduino/ESP8266 -- how to resolve flickering?

Tags: arduino-ide, led

Working with

- ESP8266 Microcontroller
- [RobotDyn AC Dimmer](https://robotdyn.com/ac-light-dimmer-module-1-channel-3-3v-5v-logic-ac-50-60hz-220v-110v.html)

The dimming works but there's occasional flickering.
Trying to trouble-shoot the cause / find a solution.

The code below is the core dimming loop.
Even stripped down strictly that code, I'm still getting the same degree of flickering.

Possible causes:

- Responsiveness / occasional hiccups on in the ESP8266?
- Responsiveness of the AC Dimmer?
- Algorithm?
- Something else?

Arduino IDE / C++

```
void loop(){
    eTime=micros()-cTime;
    if(digitalRead(ZcpPin)==HIGH){
        digitalWrite(PwrPin, LOW);
        cTime=micros();
    }else if(eTime > Delay){
        digitalWrite(PwrPin, HIGH);
    }
}
```

Comment: Periodically bedind the scenes of the arduino loop the wifi gets serviced, which may take a couple of microseconds, it could be this that you are seeing. You might want to use interrupts instead.

Comment: Thanks ximon.  Could be, but here's what's developed since that posting: The flickering seems to have to do with the use of cheap AC-to-DC transformers 1-2A. When the ESP is powered by that there is flickering.  If instead the ESP is powered by a USB/TTL cable from a MacBook Pro using the same code, no flickering.  I haven't had time to look at the transformers using an oscilloscope.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it seems to be more about hardware than software: https://arduino.stackexchange.com